# How to close one sub menu when clicking another sub menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code to control the menu.
I want to close one sub menu when I click to open another sub menu.

```
;(function($) {

    // DOM ready
    $(function() {

        // Add some classes and Append the mobile icon nav
        $('.nav').append($('<div class="nav-mobile"></div>'));
        $('.nav > ul').addClass('nav-list');
        $('.nav > ul > li').addClass('nav-item');
        $('.nav > ul > li > ul').addClass('nav-submenu');
        $('.nav > ul > li > ul > li').addClass('nav-submenu-item');

        // Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside. And add an  sub menu icon indicator.
        $('.nav-item').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i></i></span>');

        // Click to reveal the mobile menu
        $('.nav-mobile').click(function() {
            $('.nav-list').toggle();
            $('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when i click the top ribbon (.nav-mobile) to close the mobile menu
            if (!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')) { // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
                $('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function() { // loop through nav clicks
                    if ($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) { // This will toggle back the + icon on mobile menu close/open
                        $(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // Dynamic binding to on 'click' and Toggle the nested nav
        $('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function() {
            $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();

            // This will toggle the + and - when clicked
            $(this).removeClass('nav-click');
            $(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
            $(this).toggleClass('nav-click');
        });

        // This will toggle the menu/submenu/- when click outside of the menu
        $('.wrapper').click(function(event) {
            $('html').one('click', function() {
                $('.nav-list').hide();
                $('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when you click the top ribbon (hamburger button) to close the mobile menu
                if (!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')) { // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
                    $('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function() { // loop through nav clicks
                        if ($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) { // This will toggle the +/- icon on mobile menu close/open
                            $(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

    });

})(jQuery);
```

So how can I close one sub menu when clicking another sub menu?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: OK,Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/b1913dLq

Comment: Live demo: http://test3.fcab.se/responsive_menu_test/simple_multi_responsive_menu_flat/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing `nav-click` method this way should do the trick:

```
// Dynamic binding to on 'click' and Toggle the nested nav
$('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){
    $('.nav-submenu').not($(this).siblings('.nav-submenu')).hide();
    $('.nav-item .nav-click').not(this).removeClass('icon-close'); 
    $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-close');  
});
```

Firstly we are targetting all subnav elements excluding currently clicked and force to close it, then make a toggle on current elements.

Just to mention: you could achieve this more easily with plain js, or super-fast with any two-way databind framework, jquery is no-help here, but that's your choice.